# Execute code after task has been completed Azure Mobile Services and Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure Mobile Services, I need to get emails from table depending on a list of Id. I have a method that get specific item from the table by looping the list of Id and geting each item. But everithing executes before`onComplete`. This is my code:

```
private ArrayList<String> administratorsEmail = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean getAdminsEmail(List<String> adminList)
{

    for(String ids : adminList)
    {
        UsersTable.lookUp(ids, new TableOperationCallback<Users>()
        {
            public void onCompleted(Users entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
            {
                if (exception == null)
                {
                    administratorsEmail.add(entity.getEmail());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //CODE HERE EXECUTES BEFORE ONCOMPLETE
}
```

I need to fill the `administratorsEmail` list. I need to execute some code after the list `administratorsEmail` has been filled completely. But I can't put code in `onComplete` method because it would execute the same times than the loop.

I need to know when OnCompleted has finished. Any body could give a better idea or some help for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `int counter` for the amount of records there are to process, and when `counter == totalRecords` run your code.

```
public boolean getAdminsEmail(List<String> adminList)
{
int counter = 0;
int totalRecords = adminList.length();

for(String ids : adminList)
{
    UsersTable.lookUp(ids, new TableOperationCallback<Users>()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Users entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
        {
            if (exception == null)
            {
                administratorsEmail.add(entity.getEmail());
                if (++counter == totalRecords) afterCompleted();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
private void afterCompleted() {...
```

Comment: Thank you! @SZH I'll try this and let you know. Thanks for your help!!